# MKMapView not appearing when Autolayout is disabled

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, ios5, mkmapview

I am using storyboard for my map application. `MKMapview` does not appear when `Autolayout` is disabled.Enabling `Autolayout` crashes my app in `iPad(ios5)`.

Comment: did you include the MapView framework? (project settings, build phases, link binary with library)

Comment: Post some code so we can see what you are doing. Most likely something isn't hooked up properly in the `UIStoryboard`, and the `Autolayout` was keeping a reference to the `MKMapView` for you.

Comment: @Dpk I'm referring to her code in the `.m` file. I was giving a potential reason for what might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autolayout is an IOS 6 feature - so it will crash on your iPad for that reason as you say it is running iOS 5.

Set your minimum requirement to iOS 5 (which I assume you have done) and then only use feature's that relate to iOS5. The app will still run for people with iOS 6 devices:-)

Also like @msgambel said - if you are able to post some code it will be easier for us to help you. Post some screenshots if you believe the issue lies with Storyboard related stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support iOS 5 you can't use Autolayout in the Storyboard files.
So for iOS 5 you need to place the all the view elements in the old way. To use the constraints in iOS 6 you can do all the constraint setup for iOS 6 in code.

You can use the following macro to check for iOS 6

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

And then when you setup you ViewController you need to check for iOS 6

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")) {
    // code here
}
```

and bind constraints to the views.
You can find a little [tutorial to constraints here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_iOS_6_Auto_Layout_Constraints_in_Code).

If you want to use Autolayout with Storyboard or xib files you need to create a Storyboard for iOS 6 and one for iOS 5 respectively for every xib one for iOS 6 and one for iOS 5. The iOS 6 ones can use Autolayout the iOS 5 ones of course not. 
When you finished setting up the views you need to check for the iOS version and load the correct storyboard respectively xib files for the views.

For Storyboards the instantiation code would be:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")) {
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iOS6Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
} else {
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iOS5Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

When using xib for every view it is:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")) {
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControlleriOS6" bundle:nil]; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
} else {
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControlleriOS5" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Of course xib ViewController can also be presented modally as well as storyboard ViewController can be pushed with a navigation controller.